# Defending classes with 'magic numbers'

Tags: c++, security, oop

A few months ago I read a book on security practices, and it suggested the following method for protecting our classes from overwriting with e.g. overflows etc.:

- first **define a magic number** and a fixed-size array (can be a simple integer too)
- use that array containing the magic number, and **place one at the top, and one at the bottom of our class**
- **a function compares these numbers, and if they are equal**, and equal to the static variable, **the class is ok**, return true, **else it is corrupt**, and return false.
- place this function at the start of every other class method, so this will **check the validity of the class on function calls**
- it is important to place this array at the start and the end of the class

At least this is as I remember it. I'm coding a file `encryptor` *for learning purposes*, and I'm trying to make this code exception safe.

So, in which scenarios is it useful, and when should I use this method, or is this something totally useless to count on? Does it depend on the compiler or OS?

*PS: I forgot the name of the book mentioned in this post, so I cannot check it again, if anyone of you know which one was it please tell me.*

Comment: That technique is called "canary testing", and its a common technique performed to detect buffer overflows, heap corruptions, etc. Its performed by some compilers on debug mode to check the situations above (For example MSVC initialices stack frames with the value `0xCCCCCCCC` to help detecting use of uninitialized variables).

Comment: this is mainly for development.. if you hope that this will keep your production code safe, you're in trouble. (and if this is a problem for you, pick another language that doesn't let you corrupt memory)

Comment: [Nothing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow_protection#Undefendable_attacks)'s perfect.

Comment: Check [this article](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/w-p/win32/tutorials/article.php/c9535/Inside-CRT-Debug-Heap-Management.htm) for an example. LLVM satinizers are other example.

Comment: This is a debugging technique mostly not something you need to do unless you have a problem. There are also many static and runtime code analysis tools which can perform these sorts of check automatically if you use some Google-Fu ...

Comment: I find this a rather ad hoc method of guaranteeing program correctness. Just establish your class invariants inside constructors and check pre- and post conditions in member functions, e.g. using `assert()`.

Comment: @TemplateRex I don't think this technique actually "guarantees" anything at all. It only helps you notice some cases where you write through bad pointers. But it only catches certain cases of that...

Comment: thanks for the comments, I see it. So thats why I always saw the 0xccc... hex in the diassembly. @Karoly Horvath now I don't have these kind of problems, I just wondered if it can be used/is used for something

Comment: @twalberg yeah, I am still amazed at the bizarre stuff people add in their files. It took decades to make people realize not to put version info in source code but in a version control system. Ditto for checksum here, just use a dedicated file system tool.

Comment: never planned to use it for the encryption, just for the classes doing it. but now I see it's pretty worthless for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're describing sounds a [Canary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_buffer_overflow#Stack_canaries), but within your program, as opposed to the compiler. This is usually on by default when using gcc or g++ (plus a few other buffer overflow countermeasures).

If you're doing mutable operations on your class and you want to make sure you don't have side effects, I don't know if having a magic number is very useful. Why rely on a homebrew validity check when there are mothods out there that are more likely to be successful?

[Checksums:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Checksum) I think it'd be more useful for you to hash the unencrypted text and add that to the end of the encrypted file. When decrypting, remove the hash and compare the hash(decrypted text) with what it should be.

I think most, if not all, widely used encryptors/decryptors store some sort of checksum in order to verify that the data has not changed.

Comment: and what is the advantage of doing this in the source code itself rather than through the version control or file system?

Comment: I assumed the OP meant that he wanted to make sure the data he was encrypting was not corrupted.

You're right, though. The source is a filesystem problem.

Comment: I've just mentioned the purpose of the program, I'm using checksums for it already. It (the Canary) just get in my mind but did not find the book to read what is it for mainly, so asked.

Answer (score 2):

This type of a canary will partially protect you against a very specific type of overflow attack.  You can make it a little more robust by randomizing the canary value every time you run the program.

If you're worried about buffer overflow attacks (and you should be if you are *ever* parsing user input), then go ahead and do this.  It probably doesn't cost *too* much in speed to check your canaries every time.  There will always be other ways to attack your program, and there might even be careful buffer overflow attacks that get around your canary, but it's a cheap measure to take so it might be worth adding to your classes.